# Which part of שחרית would you identify as "prayer"?

Tags: tefilla, prayer-book, shacharis-morning-prayer

What part of שחרית would you identify as "prayer"?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Prayer _A practice of communicating with one's Gcd._ If you're not doing that the entire שחרית, then what are you doing with the words in your Siddur? IOW: Define _prayer_ in your question.

Comment: What is your reason to think that any part of שחרית is not prayer?

Answer (score 4):

When the *g'mara* used the term "*shacharis*" it referred to *[Sh'moneh Esre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shemoneh_esrei)*, all of which is prayer. Likewise, when it used the term *t'fila*, generally translated as "prayer", it meant *Sh'moneh Esre* alone. It is a 3- (or 4-, including supplemental petitions at the end) part prayer, beginning with praise, continuing with requests, and concluding with gratitude.

If you are referring to the entirety of the recitation in the morning, from *[Modeh Ani](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modeh_ani)* through *[Alenu L'shabe'ach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleinu)*, and using a broader definition of "prayer" than above, then the question may be more easily addressed by asking which parts are not prayer. Everything that contains one of the aforementioned elements of praise, request, or gratitude can rightly be considered prayer, which leaves a small number of [obligatory blessings](http://www.torahlab.org/calendar/article/birchas_hatorah/) at the beginning, and the recital of *[Sh'ma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shma)*.

Comment: ...but I think most people would informally consider said obligatory blessings and _Sh'ma_ "prayer" too.

Comment: @msh210 Good point. I might have mentioned that I assumed the questioner was looking for more precision than the colloquialism. I will edit in a note.

Comment: @msh210 Yes, but Sh'ma would not be prayer.  The saying of Shema is the fulfillment of the obligation to say Shema twice a day. It is the reading of verses that are in the Torah.  It is not prayer. (Berachot 2b)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I just need a little clarification.  Are you suggesting that the Tehilim that are said. such as everything between Baruch Sheamar and Az Yashir are considered prayer?  Tehilim as I understand it are simply verses David composed that are considered Ketuvim.  They are not prayer.

Comment: @RCW Basically, yes. There are many types of prayer (13 according to one version of one _midrash_ on _D'varim_ 3!) and many of them comprise forms in which the _pirkei T'hilim_ were written. Although not our own original words, we adopt the words of _T'hilim_ to express our own spiritual purposes, which sometimes consist of requests, other times of descriptive praise, and yet other times of questions and stories, all of which can constitute prayer if utilized in the right way (such as the way _Chaza"l_ laid out for us between _Baruch She'amar_ and _Yishtabach_).