# Too fast or no minyan?

Tags: tefilla, priorities, minyan, kavana-concentration, pesukei-dezimra

Suppose the only minyan available for someone to attend is one which moves far too fast for him. Even with arriving early and starting ahead of time, he only has time to say a fraction of psukei d'zimra if he wants to daven shmoneh esrei with the minyan. Suppose it would either not be possible for him to arrive early enough to daven the whole davening in time for shmoneh esrei with the group or extremely inconvenient (such as a very early pre-work minyan). Would it be preferable for him to stay home and daven on his own while saying all of psukei d'zimra with focus and attention, or is it better for him to rush, not saying all of it, but saying shmoneh esrei with a minyan?

Comment: Why stay home? You can go to Shul even if you can't keep up with them ...

Comment: You're case seems highly unlikely. However-long-it-takes-you-to-get-to-Shmone-Esrei is the same amount of time he'd be spending alone.

Comment: whereever you have most kawono that is where you should pray. a meenyon that is praying fast most likely doesnt have kawono so you might as well pray home

Comment: @Daniel Maybe you would be better off commuting to work early, arriving at the office, and then going to a later minyan around there.  Or, maybe there are 9 other men in the area who also don't want to wake up so early, or daven so fast, and you can start a minyan near where you work.  Lots of people struggle with this, so you might be successful in starting a nice, slower paced minyan.

Comment: @Jake sure but I'm not looking for solutions to the hypothetical problem here, but rather answers to the question (which you do nicely in your answer, btw)

Comment: @Daniel Thanks.  I always wonder if the questioner is asking l'maaseh or not.  Of course, CYLOR and all that, but sometimes I read a question, and I want to help the human being behind the question, hence a solution to the hypothetical problem.

Comment: Similar: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/66554

Comment: Related: "[Keeping up with fast davening](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10268/1368)", "[Falling behind during davening](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13715/1368)".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [My Rav](http://ph.yhb.org.il/en/03-14-05/#_te02ftn14_9)

- Say Elokai Neshama, Bircat HaTorah, and Bircat HaShachar
- Say Baruch She'Amar, Ashrei, and Yishtabach

If you can put on tallit and tefillin, and say just the above passages, in the time that it takes the rest of the minyan to say all of Psukei D'Zimra, then it's better to do so, in order to pray with a minyan.

This is assuming that the person is able to keep up with the minyan for shema and shemoneh esreh itself.

If not, (quote from above link)

> If one notices that he does not have time to say these berachot [bircat hatorah, elokai, bircat hashachar] and Ashrei and still succeed in praying with the minyan, he should pray individually without omitting anything.

Comment: The Lubavitcher Rebbe was against skipping any part of davening (even if you'll say it later).

Comment: @user3949142 The Shulchan Arukh though was in favor of doing so.

Comment: @DoubleAA Are you saying this as a statement or rebuttal?

Comment: @user3949142 Both.

Comment: @DoubleAA You're right, the shulchan aruch is in favor of skipping. Once the alter rebbe was asked why he paskens differently in the siddur from his shulchan aruch, he said that the shulchan aruch goes like poskim and siddur goes like mekubalim. So he was asked that he writes in shulchan aruch that when there's a machlokes you follow poskim. He answered: that's what the poskim say. Over here, it could be that the rebbe was speaking about al-pi kaballah, but i need to look at what he says again.

Comment: @user3949142 Either way, I don't know why this is happening here as this doesn't have to do with the answer. If you would like to post a different answer, go ahead.

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm just pointing out that the answer is not so clear cut, but I don't want to post another answer because he's question is not about whether you can skip.

Comment: @user3949142 The Rebbe says that he paskened that way for "practical" reasons. Once one gets used to skipping, he'll just continue that way forever

Comment: @ShmuelBrin It's true, I know several men who became frum in their late 20's / early 30's, who follow the above pattern daily for their p'sukei d'zimra.  However, they are allowed.  Who says they are required to force themselves to daven faster, so they can say more?  From a Chassidishe standpoint, one could posit that the BT's contemplative "ashrei" is more powerful and treasured in shamayim, then everyone else's rapidly recited p'sukei d'zimra.

Comment: @Jake, they could add more in their native language.

Comment: @user613 The answer is clear cut according to Halacha, which is all most Jews need to care about.

Comment: "_This is assuming that the person is able to keep up with the minyan for shema and shemoneh esreh itself_". Doesn't that negate the question's premise of the _Minyan_ going too fast? More generally: The linked page talks about arriving late to prayers. How do we know the same applies when the problem is that the  _Minyan_ is going too fast?

Answer (score 4):

[Siman 52 in Shulchan Aruch](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14170&st=&pgnum=158) is all about the Halachos of which parts of Pesukei D'zimra to skip if one comes late to shul. From the first Mishna Berura there it is apparent that the motivation for skipping parts of Pesukei D'zimra is in deference to the value of davening Shmone Esrei together with the rest of the congregation. Being that that is the case, I would extrapolate that in your case you should be skipping some of your Pesukei D'zimra as well in order to insure that you daven Shmoneh Esrei with the tzibbur. Tefila betzibbur is important enough to require one who is in shul to skip parts of davening in order to make it, I don't think that it would give any preference to staying home in order to say all of Pesukei D'zimra

Answer (score 1):

You might do what I'm doing today, which is to practice at home with a tape of the service or videos available online.  With practice comes speed.

Comment: What if I can already daven pretty fast, but the tzibbur just davens _really_ fast? I can probably say _pesukei d'zimra_ faster than most frum Jews in the world if I'm trying to speed. But when I'm davening I'd rather daven b'kavana.