# What is the Shabbos Shacharit Prayer Order? (For Nusach HaAri ideally)

Tags: tefilla, chabad, shacharis-morning-prayer, nusach-ari

I go to a Lubavitch shul which uses Nusach HaAri and half the time I have no idea what is happening during shabbos shacharit because everyone is reading to themselves and then all of a sudden the chazzan yells (page [whatever page]) and it is nowhere near the page we were on last time he announced the page. Obviously they are jumping around but I have no idea what the order of prayers is here. Especially, some prayers are repeated multiple times (so we go backwards in the siddur - but I have no idea which prayers are repeated and when), some prayers are sang, etc. I would think there is a standard order of prayers for this nusach which I simply don't know. Could someone kindly write out the order? I would really, truly appreciate it and I'll share it with the other Baal Teshuvas who are just as lost! Thank you!

Comment: Are you using a nusakh HaAri siddur like Tehilat HaShem? I think they pretty much just follow it in order, although they might go rather quickly during pesukei dezimra. I don't know exactly what you know, so forgive me if this is super obvious to you, but they will use a different book during the Torah reading, which could explain going to earlier pages: it's lower numbered pages in the chumash rather than the siddur.

Comment: I guess during the repetition of the Amida, they go backward in the siddur. First everyone says the prayer quietly and then the chazan returns to the beginning of the Amida and repeats it out loud.

Comment: Yes we use Tehilat HaShem. I know to change books when they take out the Torah. So you're saying it is basically linear and they have to get through all the pages of the shabbos shacharit, they're just blasting through it. So what am I supposed to do? Just skim it? Or just jump around as they announce the page numbers? I can't pray at 100 MPH and know what I'm saying.

Comment: You could try arriving early and starting to pray ahead of time so that you have a head start. If even that isn't enough, check out [this question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/44795/1713)

Comment: I think "what am I supposed to do if I can't keep up with the service?" would be a fine question to ask here, if it hasn't already been asked.  The answer probably involves a mix of finding ways to spend more time (arrive early) and knowing which parts you can either skip entirely or save for later.  I struggle with this in fast minyanim too.

Comment: Thanks Monica. Daniel linked above to the answer to that exact question and it did involve what you mentioned.

Comment: @Baruch I've been in the same boat before. You'll get the hang of it after a month or so.

Comment: You read what you can and with time you improve your speed, that's how it worked by me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic order of the prayers according to minhag Chabad is:

- Korbanos (Same as Weekday in the beginning of the siddur)
- Pisukei D'Zimra - For Shabbat (Passages of Songs) (different than during the week - page number is listed at end of Korbonos)
- Blessings of Shema (Shabbat - Follows Pisukei D'Zimra for Shabbat)
- Shacharit Amida Shabbat - Follows
- Song of the Day Shabbat - Follows
- Torah Reading
- Ashrei etc.
- Musaf Amidah
- Ein Cleokeinu, Incense (same as the week)
- Aleinu