# I cant focus enough to get words out during minyan; should I still go?

Tags: tefilla

It’s very hard for me to even get words out in my minyan at school because of the Hazan and the other kids and wtvr. Should I even go to minyan, or just pray by myself? Should I go pray in an ashkenaz minyan even though I’m Sephardi?

Comment: Hi, this question will be closed because it is looking for a personal psak. You can salvage it if you change it to "Should one go to minyan if they have genuine concentration problems caused by ... in shul? Does the answer differ if the shul one has access to is of a different minhag to one's own?"

Comment: highly related: [Is it more preferable to pray with concentration alone or with a minyan in shul?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/66554/11501)