# Must one be synced with the minyan?

Tags: shema, minyan

What should I do if I'm about to say the *Shema Israel* but the rest of the *minyan* is already on *aleinu leshabeach*, to give an example. Should I say *"El melej neeman"*? Do I need to be in sync with the *minyan*?

Answer (score 0):

It is very important to distinguish between saying *amidah* together with the *tzibbur* (which is the main *halacha* of *tefillah be'tzibbur*), and being in sync in other parts, which may be less important.

Here's a [good source](http://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/shiur.asp?id=25526) on this subject. It doesn't contain all possible combinations, but it gives a good understanding of the basics. And the [Pninei Halacha](http://ph.yhb.org.il/02-14-05/) on the subject.

Related:

- [Falling behind during davening](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13715/falling-behind-during-davening)
- [Keeping up with fast davening](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10268/keeping-up-with-fast-davening)