# Making mistakes in shemone esri

Tags: halacha, shemoneh-esrei, pronunciation, chazzan-prayer-leader, mistakes

I would assume at some point, too many uncorrected mistakes during the shemone esri (not talking about the things that would make it avodah zara here) would make it invalid/useless as it simply loses its meaning (literally).

At what point does this happen? Do only the brachot have the be intact? Do even those have to be intact? Should one use the same standards that they do for reading the torah? What if the sheliah tzibur makes the mistakes?

Comment: very related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15922/759

Comment: How are you distinguishing a shatz from anyone davening a private tefilla who makes a mistake?  Are you asking if we replace the shatz?

Comment: @YDK Good point. I guess I should edit it to ask how many mistakes it takes until shemone esri is invalid, and then what should be done at that point.

Comment: I don't want to vote you up. You have the perfect rep score (613)!

Comment: As far as a Hazan all the laws of if they make a mistake during the Amidah can be found in the Laws of prayer pereq 10
Hebrew: http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/2210.htm

English : http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/920173/jewish/Chapter-Ten.htm

Answer (score -1):

BS"D

> "A person who prayed without concentrating must pray a second time with concentration. However, if he had concentrated during the first blessing, nothing more is necessary.
>
> A person who errs in the recitation of the first three blessings must return to the beginning [of the Shmoneh Esreh]. Should one err in the recitation of the final three blessings, one should return to [the blessing, Rsseih].
>
> If one errs in the midst of the intermediate blessings, one should return to the beginning of that blessing and conclude one's prayers in the correct order."

[*M"T Hilkhoth Tephilah 10:1*](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/2210n.htm)

Comment: This _almost_ answers the question. But I believe what must be answered first is what constitutes a mistake. I believe the question is primarily about mispronouncing words, and whether that (or too much of it) invalidates prayer.

Comment: Hmm thats strange cause the only reason i posted that was because I thought it did talk about what you're saying it doesn't lol. 
I thought when it says "A person who errs in the recitation" dictates what would make some one have to go back. So like you said mispronouncing words or the like since thats an err of the recitation. I also thought it was related becuse it informs where one would have to start over if one did err. 
So, Why a person would have to start over and Where he would have to start from, is that not the question?

Comment: @Sethj i also included the laws of the Hhazan in a comment in the OP.