# Correcting the Shaliach Tzibbur

Tags: tefilla, mistakes, chazzan-prayer-leader

As far as I can see, we still view the repetition of the Amida as an obligation (as indicated in footnote two, [here](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Chazarat_HaShatz#Practices_of_the_Shaliach_Tzibur)), and require the Shatz to be precise and say the right prayers in order to fulfill this obligation, so much so that we correct the Chazzan if he makes mistakes regarding insertions, changes or omissions (as per #7 [here](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Chazarat_HaShatz#If_the_Shaliach_Tzibur_made_a_mistake), and the language of "when he is corrected").

There are also laws regarding who is a viable choice to represent the kahal in prayer, including [rules](http://www.torahmusings.com/2011/07/mispronouncing-hebrew/) which sometimes bar and sometimes allow someone who mis- (or differently) pronounces words.

If someone davening for the amud and repeating shmoneh esrei skips words or mispronounces them, is there an obligation to correct him the way a gabbai would correct someone reading from the Torah (assuming that the nature of the mispronunciation or omission would, in a parallel Torah reading case, qualify for being corrected)?

Comment: As you say, I don't see why a Shatz is different from anyone else in any other blessing. So it should be the same as http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/15925/759 : even if he gets one word wrong, he still might have formed a valid Berakha.

Comment: possible dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18989/759

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/34213/759 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/34311/759

Comment: Note: If you do correct him, make sure to address him and correct him respectfully. (Sorry, had to say that. I do not know the halacha on this.)

Comment: @EzraHoerster My fear is that if I correct him, I will be interrupting my own participation in the repetition (as per http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16964/1362) and lose out on that kiyyum.

Comment: @danno correcting is letzorekh and not a hefsek, just like correcting a baal keriya (you are also participating in the leining by listening, I assume)

Comment: @DoubleAA I would have to investigate what the actual obligation is in kriat hatorah. Is it my listening, or my being as if I am doing the reading. If the Rambam's position is that I am a participant and must maintain a certain physical attitude then that might be different from my comportment obligation during leining.

Comment: @Danno There's no point in maintaining any attitude if he's not saying the Chazarat haShatz... IAE if it's letzorekh it's not a hefsek so you've maintained all necessary attitudes.

Comment: @DoubleAA agreed but if a gabbai or someone else corrects him, then I don't have to and can fulfill whatever my requirement as. Alternatively, if he doesn't need to be corrected (the article about who is a viable chazzan allows those who mispronounce to daven in some cases), then I shouldn't say anything.

Comment: @Danno Why is a gabbai less obligated than you to particpate? Why does correcting mess up your fulfilling your requirement??

Comment: @DoubleAA My only solution when I wrote that was to suggest the position of a gabbai who had already davened with a minyan. I am not clear on what kind of talking would be a hefsek during the commission of any mitzvah so I don't know what would constitute that problematic level of hefsek (and how that is balanced against "need to correct" vs. "want to correct").