# Kaddish not being said correctly

Tags: halacha, mourning-aveilus, kaddish, amen

Should one respond to a Kaddish that a mourner is not pronouncing the words properly?

I don’t know if this question has been asked before, but I found something similar - [Is there such a thing as a Kaddish L'vatola?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35324/)

Comment: Possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15922/759

Comment: I imagine there are many people saying Kaddish who are not too observant and not too fluent in reading Hebrew. If one should not respond to their Kaddish, would it suggest that God won’t respond either? There are Chasidish tales of Am Haaretz prayers (consisting of nothing more than reciting the aleph-bet) being more loved by God than those prayers uttered even by Tzaddiks.