# Does it still count as a Bracha if one stuttered and repeated words?

Tags: tefilla, blessing, mitzvah

What if someone has a stutter and they tend to repeat words when doing a Bracha. As long as they said all of the words, does it still count as a Bracha?

Comment: They should talk to a Rabbi for advice for their situation.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15922/27180