# Ashkenazic Practice of the Chazan saying only certain phrases (rashei perkaim) out loud

Tags: tefilla, ashkenazi

What is the source of the Ashkenazic practice of the Chazzan saying only certain words out loud? That is, in your typical Artscroll siddur, there are markings for the Chazzan to raise his voice and say a portion of the text.

[image]

There is apparently a distinction here between Ashkenazic and Sefardic practice. [Thus](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/365941/jewish/The-Cantor-Chazan-Hazzan.htm):

> In Ashkenazi tradition, the chazan reads the opening and closing lines of every paragraph of the prayers aloud, reciting the body of the prayers quietly along with everyone else. In Sephardic communities, however, virtually all the prayers are read aloud by the chazan (or a series of volunteers during certain parts of the service).

What is the halachic basis for this practice?

**Note**: This is related to closed [this prior question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/138555/ashkenazi-speed-mumble-davening-origins-and-halachic-basis), which also asked about the repercussions of the practice in that people mumble, and how that impacted her own ability to focus on the words. Commenters assumed therefore that the entire question was not about minhag but about people acting incorrectly. A good answer to this present question might also address people mumbling, either as what is being incorrectly perceived, or as an unfortunate impact. [This source](https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/from-the-ravs-desk-davening-out-loud-the-chabad-custom/) and [this source](https://ph.yhb.org.il/en/category/tefila/04-the-chazan-and-the-mourners-kaddish/) might also be helpful in answering the overall question.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/83164/759

Comment: Another possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/54/2

Comment: I would ask where the Sefardi custom comes from. Seemingly everything not said out loud doesn't need to be, we only say d'varim sheb'kdusha out loud, because they need ten men. The chazan saying anything at all is probably so people know what pace to Daven at and will be in the same part of davening for when it matters

Comment: @Loani some things the chazzan says aloud to fulfill the obligation of the community and/or illiterate people. See my link above.